Trailing actor's bars (too long) for a sequence diagram, how to cut them short?
I am using the following latex lib to create my sequence diagram:
https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-umlsd
The diagram I am creating requires asyncronous calls where the actor receiving from another doesn't necessarly return to the same actor (according to the docs such link is created using messcall and not call)
Now the sequence is created successfully but the bars (of the actors) are longer than needed.
The question is how to trim them short?
Illustration of the problem is in the attached image.

Code
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sequencediagram} 
        \newthread{t}{User} 
        
        \newinst{a}{} 
        \newinst{b}{} 
        \newinst{c}{}
        
        \begin{call}{t}{Detect}{a}{} 
            \begin{sdblock}{Computer}{}
                \begin{call}{a}{Dispatch}{b}{response} 
                \end{call} 
            \end{sdblock}
            \begin{call}{a}{Dispatch}{c}{} 
                \begin{call}{c}{response}{t}{}  
                \end{call}
            \end{call} 
        \end{call} 
    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}


@Patrik Schulz: Could you please add a Minimal Working Example (MWE) to your question? Otherwise it is very difficult to find a solution for your problem.

Could you please share the complete LaTeX source code you used to generate the image shown in your question? Please add it to your original question as a code example.
A Minimal Working Example (MWE) needs to contain all the loaded packages and settings, because otherwise one could easily miss an important fact.

@dsacre check code update

From the sparse documentation of the pgf-umlsd package it seems that
\begin{call}{<CALLER>}{<DESCRIPTOR FORWARD>}{<CALLEE>}{<DESCRIPTOR RETURN>}
    <CODE>
\end{call}

always creates a return path, even when setting the <DESCRIPTOR RETURN> to empty. When I compile the MWE, the result is:

 So clearly the blocks are as long as they need to be in the case of a return call.
Replacing \begin{call} with \begin{messcall} only seems to suppress the drawing of the arrows, but the size of the call boxes is not adjusted. I am afraid that it is not possible to change that without modifying the source code of the package, as the manual does not mention any settings which could help to rectify the problem completely.
Best solution so far
Code
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sequencediagram} 
        \newthread{t}{User} 
        
        \newinst{a}{} 
        \newinst{b}{} 
        \newinst{c}{}
    
        \begin{messcall}[0]{t}{Detect}{a}{}
            \begin{sdblock}{Computer}{}
                \begin{call}{a}{Dispatch}{b}{response} 
                \end{call} 
            \end{sdblock}
            \begin{messcall}[0]{a}{Dispatch}{c} 
                \begin{messcall}[1]{c}{\phantom{\hspace{1cm*\unitfactor}}response}{t}
                \end{messcall}
            \end{messcall} 
        \end{messcall}
    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}

Result

Comments

Setting the optional height parameter of \begin{messcall}[<OPTIONAL HEIGHT>]{<CALLER>}{<MESSAGE>}{<CALLEE>} to 0 helps a little, but still not great. Unfortunately, the optional argument does not take float input (it seems to be parsed to some fixed (integer) step), so it is impossible to fine tune.
There is no direct way of adjusting the position of messages. The message text is hard coded in the package source code as \path .... node[midway, above]{<TEXT>};, so without modifying the package source code, there is no direct access to the node alignment properties. However, there is a somewhat hacky workaround: TikZ nodes accept \hspace{} commands when they are wrapped into a \phantom{}. Digging a bit the package source code revealed that the distance between instances/threads is defined by the macro \unitfactor. So multiplying a distance with \unitfactor and creating a horizontal offset via \phantom{\hspace{1cm*\unitfactor}} allows to make the text seem larger to TikZ than it actually is, so that the text position shifts without changing the position of the node.


I am reading nowhere the [<OPTIONAL HEIGHT>] for messcall could you point out to that in the docs?

also could the label response (in the bottom) be shifted to the right a bit?

The documentation does not explicitly contain information about [<OPTIONAL HEIGHT>]. That I found out about this was pure coincidence, because TeXStudio suggested the optional parameter during macro auto completion. Afterwards, I dug a bit deeper in the examples shown in the documentation: E.g. it is used in section 3.2, Multithreads, page 7, line 5. But I could find no mention/explanation whatsoever in the official documentation for version 0.7.

Some more information could be hidden in the official pgf-umlsd demo on github. There seem to be some examples which are not included in the manual (or at least the official manual on CTAN for version 0.7).

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to adjust the alignment of "response" provided by the package itself. This text is hard coded in the package source code as \path .... node[midway, above]{<TEXT>};, so without modifying the package source code, there is no direct access to the node alignment properties.

@PatrickSchulz: I added a workaround for positioning message texts to my answer.

\phantom{\hspace{1cm*\unitfactor}} gives the error Package calc Error: `.' invalid at this point.

@PatrickSchulz: The MWE I posted in my answer compiles on my machine with TeXlive 2023 without any errors. With what and how do you compile your document?

@PatrickSchulz: I tested now also on Overleaf: For all the versions I tested (TeXlive 2017 to TeXlive 2024), the MWE from my answer compiled without any error messages in general and consequently also no package calc error. I am afraid I do not know what the issue might be.

there was indeed an error, but \phantom{\hspace{1cm}} (remove \unifactor) fixed it

@Patrick Schulz: When I explicitly load the calc package, I can reproduce your error message.  it seems like there is a clash between the calc and pgf-umlsd packages.  Like you also mentioned, removing the \unitfactor resolves that issue. However, this requires additional manual adjustment of the message text position (since \unitfactor provides the information about the distance between threads).

@PatrickSchulz: A tip for asking future questions on TeX.SX: Always try to give a MWE that can be compiled and specify all the packages you load/add to a posted solution. E.g. without the information that you actively added the calc package to your preamble, I had to assume the issue is an internal request of the calc package that is handled differently for different TeX installations and therefor could not immediately reproduce your error.
